# Set permission to SharePoint 2010 site to ALL users of Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I have created web-app in SharePoint 2010 using workgroup layout. 
I can assign users from my Active Directory manually.

Is there a way to allow access to all AD automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [well known security identifier](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330) `Authenticated Users` or `Domain users` (depending on your exact needs)

Comment: thank you! I just specified it in this way - [Domain]\[AD group with all users]